# Want to make a boolean field to behave like a radio button with its associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My application has an Image class, polimorphically associated to different classes. So each of these objects has a set of images, and I want to be able to set one of them as the featured image.

So I added an `is_featured` field to the Image class, and I wanted to make sure there is only one image per associated object with this field set to true.

So what I was trying is to override the setter method for this field. This what I got so far, but it doesnt work (it doesnt set the rest of the `is_featured` fields to `false`):

```
def is_featured=(is_featured_value)
  if is_featured_value == true
    current_featured = self.imageable.featured_image
    if current_featured and current_featured != self
      current_featured.write_attribute(:is_featured, false)
    end
  end
  super(is_featured_value)
end
```

Anyone know what isnt working?

BTW I know there are probably better ways to do this, like using a `featured_image_id` field in the associated object, but at this point I'd like to know how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to iterate over all the OTHER records,  which you're not doing.  I think you think the call to super may be doing that for you,  but it isn't.

You'd need it to look something like:

```
def is_featured=(is_featured_value)
  if is_featured_value == true
    ???.each do |i|
       if i.id == self.id
         i.is_featured = true
       else
         i.is_featured = false
       end
    end
  else
    self.is_featured = false
  end
end
```

Now what ??? is depends on how you've got your relationships set up,  You haven't shown enough of your code to know for sure.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention than the "imageable" objects have a featured_image method that return the image with the is_featured field set to true, if there is one. That method is very simple and works perfetly, so I dont think that is the problem. I will try iterating over all of them just in case.